# Android - cannot use external library

Tags: android

I was asked to make a project work in Android and I am a complete noob in this aspect and, well... things are not working...

I have created a little code in Java which uses libraries - this code works perfectly. I am now trying to make this code work on Android but I have problems...
It seems I cannot use any element from the libraries I imported to my Android project. The project loads on the phone perfectly fine when no instance of the library is created, but when I make use of the library the app crashed and I get errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxVDX.jpg

Here is what the project package looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u94bf.jpg

The part with the arrow is what I think makes the program crashed. When I remove this line, everything works fine.

I checked online about problems with Android and external libraries but I could not understand everything... Could you help me pinpoint exactly what is wrong and how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I first started android development.
Key to this is to the external library seems to require them being another android project itself, instead of java project. After creating this android project, right click on the "external project" and choose properties. Under Android Tab, there should be something to check to denote that it is a library instead of application. After doing this, the linking is quite similar to how we link normal java projects to external java library

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I didn't understand you I think. Do you mean I should create an Android project with my libraries and then go to properties? Because when I go to properties/Android in my main Android project I get this: http://i.imgur.com/S7Epr.jpg

Comment: Yes this was what I was referring to actually, the one in your screenshot. It seems that you have already checked the "Is Library" field. First off, for the main android project, DO NOT check on "Is Library". Like what you say, create a new android project, then go to its property and check on "Is Library"

Comment: Therefore, in doing so, you should have 2 android projects. 1 will be the main project, the other is for library

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what do I put in the "library project"? I just copy all the classes of my java libraries?

Comment: If you still do not understand, you might want to list down which of the projects is library and which is for application. Then I will tell you which to check on "Is Library". Sorry that I do not have the IDE with me to screenshot for you right now

Comment: In a way, yes. Most of the classes used by Java are similar to Android. So the safest way is to go to new android library project, create a new class file, and copy over the code. If lazy, there should not be much problem copying the java class files directly to this project through

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, than just create a "libs" folder in project root and drop your external libraries there. 
Alternatively you Right-click on the jar file > build path > add to build path

Comment: Wow, OK so things are better - I copied the ntire library to a "libs" folder inside my project workspace. I have no error problems coming from Eclipse. However when I transfer the project to the phone I get the error "The application XXX has dropped unexpectedly", a thing that doesn't occur when I am not using the library. Do you think it is still a library problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: OMG, I am so ashamed... so the problem was this: when copying the library to the "libs" folder I copied the whole source code for the library and then added the .jars from sub-folders of the libs folder. When copying the .jars in the libs folder directly (and not subfolders of libs) the problem seems to be gone...

Comment: Oh yea, i just meant jar files :-). If this solved the issue, can you please mark the question as answered for benefit of other users.

Comment: Alright, yes. And for the record of future users, I was using Eclipse v1.9 and it wasn't working. Upgrading to version 3.1 solved the problem! Thanks a lot for the help.